# postgresql multitenant schemas vs databases

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, database-schema, multi-tenant

We've designed a multitenant system (lets say hundreds of tenants, not thousands). There is no shared data. The database is PostgreSQL. Is it better to create a separate database per tenant or schema?

What are the pros and cons? What is the impact on the filesystem, DB engine tables/views like locks, objects privileges, etc. - will they be much bigger in a multiple schema solution? Separate databases should be easier to backup/restore.

I know there are lots of similar questions, but most relate to cases with shared data, which is a major drawback to multiple databases, and we do not have such a requirement.

Answer (score 5):

If you never need to use tables from multiple tenants in a single query, I'd go for separate databases.

The raw speed of queries is not really affected by this and neither is the impact on the filesystem or memory.

However the query optimizer tends to get slower with many schemas and many table (but we are talking hundreds of thousands here). Tab-completion is `psql` is also not as efficient in that case.

It's also a tad easier to use pg_dump/pg_restore with separated databases than with separated schemas.

But it's a blurry line and the actual answer can very well be based on personal opinion and preferences.

Comment: The only problem I see is that connection pools in java support different usernames in same pool, but not different databases. With this limitation you need separate pool per database, and by tenant if you choose db per tenant.. it does not look good if it comes to number of connections kept alive (idle but anyway). I am thining about some hybrid approach or maybe not use connection pool at all, as creating connections is not that time consuming in most cases